# no database on my android phone

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite

I am attempting to create a database in my Android app.  It has worked, but when I restart the emulator I receive an error that indicates that my table does not exist.  I have found that my `"OnCreate"` is not started and there is no directory on my `sd` card of my app? Can you help me find my mistake?

My code is:

```
public DatabaseVerwerker(Context context) {
    super(context, database_naam, null, database_version); 
}

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS variabel (key TEXT, value TEXT);");
)
```

And will the database still exists after close and open the app?

Greatings,

I hope it's my last post of android. it get's to mutch

Comment: The little code you posted looks ok. Start with the exception stacktrace and work backwards from there.

Comment: `i have found that my "OnCreate" is not started` Maybe you don't create the DataBaseHelper object correctly in the calling Activity or Fragment or Class? `ther is no directory on my sd card of my app` Normally, the path is `/data/data/your.app.name/databases/your.db`.

Comment: @DerGolem 
all my functions to get data from the sd card is from that class so it must make him, and "DatabaseVerwerker" works, i have check it with log.v();

the database file is on the phone and not on the SD?

Comment: `"DatabaseVerwerker" works` ... How do you **instantiate** it? `the database file is on the phone and not on the SD?` **unclear** what you mean.

Comment: @DerGolem

DatabaseVerwerker DB = new DatabaseVerwerker(context);
            int DatabaseLiveTot = Integer.parseInt(DB.GetVar(DB, "keep_alive"));

Comment: Comment out this line: `int DatabaseLiveTot = Integer.parseInt(DB.GetVar(DB, "keep_alive"));`

Comment: @DerGolem i get a error on that line **no such table: variabel (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT value FROM variabel WHERE key = keep_alive at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:205**

Comment: You can't use `key` as a field name. `KEY` is a reserved keyword for SQLite. Therefore, your table is not created. For reference: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

Comment: @DerGolem Sorry, after change key to name the error is the same **no such table: variabel (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO variabel(value,naam) VALUES (?,?)**

Comment: @DerGolem this is my code http://www.codeshare.io/5w091

Comment: What you can do is: go to `/data/data/be.moviechecker.programma.moviechecker/databases/` and delete the file `database`. Re-start the app.

Comment: @DerGolem i cant find the file, my phone is not rooted. Do i need special premision for a database?

Comment: No, I mean from the IDE - Supposing you debug using an emulator.

Comment: @DerGolem i cant work with Device Monitor, i cant find a device wen they running.

Comment: Because you didn't create the **AVD**s? You **must** create some Virtual Device/s, in order to run the emulator/s. And you **should** always test the app on **emulators**, before testing it via the USB cable.

Comment: @DerGolem i use the AVD, i have the 4_7 WXGA (api 16). I test all the time with that one.

Comment: @DerGolem do i have it rong on this code: codeshare.io/CT0aB, thanks to help me i know my ENG is not good

Comment: @DerGolem, Thanks it works again. i must build the onUpdate function and trigger it.

Comment: `trigger it` means update the DATABASE_VERSION constant to a higher level. I didn't know you changed your db structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks it works again. i must build the onUpdate function and trigger it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your database has been created before you do your operation on database. The better way to create a database only used by your application is using `openOrCreateDatabase`. Here is the example.

```
    CursorFactory cursorFactory = new CursorFactory() {

        @Override
        public Cursor newCursor(SQLiteDatabase db, SQLiteCursorDriver masterQuery,
                String editTable, SQLiteQuery query) {
            return null;
        }
    };
    openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, MODE_PRIVATE, cursorFactory, new DatabaseErrorHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onCorruption(SQLiteDatabase dbObj) {
        }
    })
```